# Bolt CMS Twig - How to render total item count button after meet certain condition

Tags: symfony, twig, bolt-cms

Let's say I have latest item list with contenttypes `items` for my bolt hompage website that I get from this code in my index.twig:

`{% setcontent latestitems = 'items/latest/8' %}`

then I iterate it with `for` function so I get a list of item.

```
{% for item in latestitems %}
  ...
{% endfor %}
```

Then I want to add a button at the bottom of item list if amount of items in bolt database more than 8 with text inside button: "Read another xxx items" which xxx is total amount of items after subtracted by total items in latest item (in this case is 8). If total item in database is less than 8, it won't show up.

My question is what code that can make this method work? I use this code for my current template with `length` filter but still doesn't work:

```
{% if items|length > 8 %}
  <button>Read another {{ items|length - 8 }} items</button>
{% endif %}
```

Here's a picture that I expected

[picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/adsq3.png)

Anyone can help me correct the code?

Answer (score 1):

Straight up, this is better done in an extension as `setcontent` is designed to get records, not statistical data.

But you can do something like this:

```
{% setcontent items = 'items' nohydrate %}
{% set itemscount = items|length %}
```

That would give you the variable `itemscount` set to the total number of records for that ContentType. Note the `nohydrate` in the first line above, that will speed up the database look up for you.

Comment: Thank you @gawain for getting me help. But sorry I still don't get it. How to get the latest 8 item if variable from `setcontent items` doesn't contain `items/latest/8`? I use this variable only for iterate the item list items and I think `items|length` can directly mentioned without include it in `set itemscount`. Besides, the `items|length > 8` only going to affect the button to show up after total items in database (not in `latestitem` variable) more than 8, lest than 8 it will still hidden. Correct me if I'm wrong :)

Comment: You would still `{% setcontent latestitems = 'items/latest/8' %}` as they are the records you want to iterate, the example above is to get you "… list if amount of items in bolt database …"

Comment: Hey, I already fix this as what I want. I leave the `latestitems` variable block as what is was. I show the button using `{% setcontent items = 'items/' %}` then apply `length` filter to `items` variable and set the condition `> 8` to make sure it only shows up when the items exceed the condition. The items counter works using `{{ items|length - 8 }}` so it shows the total items subtracted by 8 which is the total of latest item list above it. And anyway thank you about `nohydrate` options. It speeds up the database :).

Comment: This is a good question but, no answer provided after 4 years and 5 months. If this question has been solved please let us know by answering this question. If OP finds the solution himself please provide the solution in answer.